# How to define a File response for OpenApi in AspNetCore

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, openapi, swashbuckle

I´m writing a Controllermethod in AspNet Core 5 that should return a file as stream.

```cs
[HttpGet]
[Route("/docs/{id}")]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetDocumentAsync([FromRoute][Required] Guid? id)
{
    var (stream, fileExtension) = await _dmsService.OpenDocumentAsync(id.Value, FileAccess.Read);
    return File(
        stream,
        contentType: "application/octet-stream",
        fileDownloadName: $"{id}{fileExtension}",
        enableRangeProcessing: false);
}
```

So far everything works but now I want to document the API.
Im using [Swashbuckle.AspNetCore 6.1.4](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/) to generate the OpenAPI description which than should be used to generate a client.

When I return some object it´s easy by using `ActionResult<T>` as return type.
But **how can I tell Swashbuckle that the response is a `stream`?**

Comment: Look at here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43844261/what-is-the-correct-way-to-download-a-file-via-the-nswag-code-generator-angular

Answer (score 4):

```
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(FileStreamResult), (int)HttpStatusCode.OK)]
```

Answer (score 0):

I use NSWAG to create the client code automatically from the MapGet.

```
builder.MapGet(
    "download/{path}",
    async ( string path) =>
    {
        var mimeType = "audio/wav";
        return Results.File(path);

    })
    .Produces(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound)
    .Produces((int)StatusCodes.Status200OK, typeof(FileResult))
    .WithName($"GET {EndPointName} by Name")
    .WithTags(EndPointTag);
```